# Is there a way of getting a sessionStorage using Karate DSL?

Tags: javascript, java, karate, session-storage

I currently need to get an authentication token that is being held under a sessionStorage key and use it on other API calls. I'm using Karate UI automation to access the browser and get to the page but I wasn’t able to access sessionStorage. I also thought about using some JS to get it, but I’m not sure if will work. Does anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy using `script()`. I just tried these 2 statements in a test and it worked fine:

```
* script("sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')")
* match script("sessionStorage.getItem('foo')") == 'bar'
```

I'm using version 0.9.5.RC5 and the documentation is here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#script

Comment: I wasn’t aware of this script() functionality! I was reading the documentation from master branch, not develop. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an API call which logs you in and gets the sessionStorage key?
You could create a feature file which sends details to log in, then records the sessionStorage key you get back from the response.

e.g.
Background:

```
* def userData = read('classpath:userData.json')

Scenario: Login user and get session token for subsequent tests
Given baseUrl 'www.yoursite.com/LoginRequest'
And request userData
When method POST
Then status 200
And def r = response
* def token = r.Key1
* header Authorization = token
```

Then any time you need to get the sessionStorage key you could call that feature file.