# How to interact with network tab in chrome using karate DSL when doing web automation

Tags: karate

I am writing UI automation script using karate DSL. In this at certain point I need to get value from network call in chrome. I want to interact with one of the webservice call in chrome devtools network tab and get the json response of that webservice.

I need this because I have to extract the value from that particular call and pass it on to the next step in my automation script. 
I have seen the question related to sessionStorage([Is there a way of getting a sessionStorage using Karate DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743094/is-there-a-way-of-getting-a-sessionstorage-using-karate-dsl)) but I wonder how to do the same for network call using script command or any other way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend is don't forget that Karate is an API testing tool at its core. Maybe all you need to do is manually make that call and get the response. You should be able to scrape the HTML and get the host and parameters needed.

That said - there's a new feature (only for Chrome) which is documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#intercepting-http-requests - and is available in 0.9.6.RC2

It may not directly solve for what you want, but in a Karate mock, you should be able to set a value for use later e.g. by using a Java singleton or writing to a temp-file.

If there is something oddly more specific you need, please contribute code to Karate. Finally, there is an experimental way in which you can actually make raw requests to the Chrome DevTools session: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test#devtools-protocol-tips - it is for advanced users, but maybe you are one :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't answer the question. Karate is UI automation tool too. Sometimes in my tests I want to use data returned by API requests called during the interaction with UI and I have hard time trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @BorisFrenkel this is a very rare use case so hardly anyone has requested this. perhaps you can contribute code ? feel free to open a feature request