Is there any way to get the request URL in karate UI test? not the current url in browser, because the site can’t be reached
when I do UI test in karate, I want to get a request url from web, the page will not load, every time the request url will have a unique code in it, the code is what I need in later test.
I cannot use * def actualUrl = waitForUrl('*') to get it because it will give "chrome-error://chromewebdata/", and * def currentUrl = driver.execute_Script("return window.location.href;") is not able to use, karate says execute_Script is not a defined method.
Please help, thank you
enter image description here

Sounds like the page wasn't even loaded.
See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813293/143475
Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61678536/143475

seems different with what I need...I don't have to open a new tab, I don't have the whole expected request either,,,,the reason I need the request url is, everytime that request will give a unique code at last of the url, and I want to get that code...the page will not loaded, I just want to get that request url from UI test. Could you please help?

I have found a method to solve my question:
def frameTree = driver.send({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' })

I can use this sentence to get the unreachableUrl
